# Blocks Rest API rest_cannot_delete

Tags: multisite, author, rest-api, block-editor, authentication

I'm trying to make a Postman call to the Wordpress API to delete a block. 
However, I keep getting a `403`. This user is used to add and delete pages, tags, and posts just fine using the `Application Passwords` Plugin for authentication. The user is an `Administrator`.

I have no idea why I don't have permissions. I can delete in the UI.

I suspect I am not adding a needed parameter to the creation call such as context or a template. But I don't know what values those should be. I hope someone here as experience with using Blocks in the REST API.

ERROR:

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_delete",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to delete this post.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

I'm deleting these blocks using the API with a call like this:

```
curl -X DELETE \
  'http://<IP_ADDRESS>/<SUBSUTE>/wp-json/wp/v2/blocks/59?force=1' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic <Token>' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: ' \
  -H 'Host: <IP>' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: <TOKEN>' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

I'm creating these blocks using the API with a call like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://<SITE>/<SUBSITE>/wp-json/wp/v2/blocks?title=BLOCKS%20TITLE&content=BLOCKS%20CONTENT' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic <TOKEN>' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: ' \
  -H 'Host: <IP>' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: <TOKEN>' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Comment: You mentioned you're using the Application Passwords plugin for authentication; did you include `--user "USERNAME:PASSWORD"` in the cURL request?

Comment: yes, I have the `Authorization: Basic <Token>` header. It's worked for everything else. <Token> is the `username:password` in Base64 encoded already.

Comment: Actually, the problem is not the plugin (as I mentioned earlier). But I think you (or that user) doesn't have the `delete_blocks` permission? Try `$user = get_userdata( 'USER ID' ); $user->add_cap( 'delete_blocks' );` and run the REST API request for deleting the block.

Comment: Ahhh do I do that in the `wp_config.php`? I'm not trying to mess with any custom Rest API points. I'm actually building documentation on what's already there for anyone who wants to use the default Rest API. Just clearing up that none of this is for any Wordpress development. I'll try adding that and let you all know

Comment: Please ignore that code and install & activate the User Role Editor plugin. Then, 1) Go to Settings -> User Role Editor and check "Show Administrator role..". 2) Go to Users -> User Role Editor and [follow these steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLw7K.png).

Comment: Awesome, I think I'll just include this in my documentation as I'm trying to just document as much of the barebones Wordpress API without plugins as possible. Thank you :)